# Channel not receiving any values if sending to many values

Tags: go, goroutine

If I pass more than 12 for `totalValues` to `getResults()`, no values are read from channel `resultCh` and I get `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`:

```
package main

type result struct {
    index int
    count int
}

func getResults(indexCh chan int, resultCh chan result, totalValues int) {
    allFields := make([]int, totalValues)

    for i := range allFields {
        indexCh <- i
        println("Sent value", i)
    }

    println("Sent all values")

    for i := 0; i < totalValues; i++ {
        value := <-resultCh
        println("Received result", value.index)

        allFields[value.index] = value.count
    }

    println("Done processing")
}

func processValue(indexCh chan int, ch chan result) {
    for index := range indexCh {
        println("Received value", index)

        ch <- result{
            index: index,
            count: index * index,
        }

        println("Sent result", index)
    }
}

func main() {
    bufferDepth := 4
    indexCh := make(chan int, bufferDepth)
    resultCh := make(chan result, bufferDepth)

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        go processValue(indexCh, resultCh)
    }

    // Value > 12 results in goroutine asleep
    getResults(indexCh, resultCh, 12)
}
```

The above code works by launching four goroutines using function `processValue()` that read values from buffered channel `indexCh`. Integers 0 to `totalValues` are inserted into `indexCh` by `getResults()`. `processValue()` processes the value and puts the result onto buffered channel `resultCh`, which is read by a `getResults()`.

I only only observe this problem when `totalValues` is greater than 12. No  values are read from `resultCh` because "Received result..." is not printed.

If I increase `bufferDepth` to five, the program completes successfully for  `totalValues` > 12 and < 15.

The program also completes successfully if the buffer depth of `resultCh` matches `totalValues`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResults` starts by writing all values to the channel. There are 4 goroutines listening, so each picks up those values, and they are blocked writing to the result channel. Channels have buffer sizes of 4. So 4 goroutines each can write a total of 4 values to result channel before blocking.

4 goroutines + 4 index channel size + 4 result channel size = 12 entries

After that, the `processValue` is blocked at writing to the channel, because `getResults` are also blocked writing to the `indexCh`.

Comment: `processValue` is writing to `resultCh`. Why would that get blocked by `getResults` writing to `indexCh`?

Comment: While `getResults` is writing to `indexCh`, it is not reading from `resultCh`. Thus, when the `resultCh` buffer is full after 4 writes, all goroutines writing to `resultCh` will block.